# A more efficient way to remove all characters that dont match unicode regex pattern from string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, emoji

I have a column that could contain emojis and text together, I need to replace all non-emoji characters from the substrings and keep the emojis exclusively

```
emojis
' andá coño'
''
' me da risa'
```

I{m expecting this result:_

```
emojis
''
''
''
```

This is working:

```
abc123 = [' ','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6', '7', '8', '9','!',',','.','?','¿','ñ','é','ó','á','ú','í','%','(',')','*','_','-','"','@','/',';',':','¡','=','+','’','[',']','>','“','”']
for i in abc123:
    df['emojis'] = df['emojis'].str.replace(i, "", regex=False)
    df['emojis'] = df['emojis'].str.replace(i.upper(), "", regex=False)
```

It's just not time efficient and iterating like that has a huge impact on script performance, I tried using a regex replace like:

```
df['emojis'] = df['emojis'].replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9-\\().:«»~-]","", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

but  this is replacing all characters including emojis.

any suggestions to make this more efficient?

Comment: You're replacing the inverse class with `[^...`

Comment: Take a look at `emojis` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove `'^'`, as stated by [Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist) in the comments
- `'\s'` gets spaces
- `'\w'` gets all word characters, including `'á ñ'`
- `'\d'` gets all digits

```py
import pandas as pd
from string import punctuation as punc

# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'emojis': ["' andá coño97979!)(,.:'", "''", "' me da risa'"]})

                      emojis
0  ' andá coño97979!)(,.:'
1                        ''
2           ' me da risa'

df.emojis.replace(f"[\s\w\d\\({punc}).:«»~-]","", regex=True, inplace=True)

  emojis
0     
1      
2
```

Comment: Awesome, that's almost there, anything similar for punctuation? Thanks!